# What are the best method to scrape the data from the website?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I need an idea for extracting the data from 990 form schedule J where we can filter the taxpayer name and scrape the data. Is there a way.
Is there a way to scrape this - part II. I have attached a link.
https://projects.propublica.org/nonprofits/organizations/452766110/202031279349301913/IRS990ScheduleJ

extract the data from schedule J

Answer (score 0):

You could explore Selenium Webdriver; the tricky part is figuring out the names/tags of the web elements that you want to get extract the data from.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).